# Execute wmctrl commands in xinitrc

Tags: linux, xorg, xmonad, wmctrl

I'm using XMonad configured to accept commands through `wmctrl` and would like to start up a few applications through `xinitrc` and move them to a certain workspace.

Those commands work, when I use the through the terminal:

```
# Launch a terminal with ncmpcpp and move it to workspace 9
urxvt -e ncmpcpp && wmctrl -r ncmpcpp -t 9
```

But if I try to put them into my `.xinitrc` they are not working anymore. The applications start-up, but aren't moved to the correct screen. I suspect this is because the calls execute before xmonad has been executed.

`xinitrc`:

```
(urxvt -e ncmpcpp && wmctrl -r ncmpcpp -t 9) &
exec xmonad
```

I already tried adding a sleep-period, but this did not help either and I would like to get this working reliably:

```
(urxvt -e ncmpcpp && sleep 5 && wmctrl -r ncmpcpp -t 9) &
exec xmonad
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute xmonad before launching terminals and trying to move them.

```
xmonad &
(urxvt -e ncmpcpp && wmctrl -r ncmpcpp -t 9)
```

Comment: Isn't the purpose of `exec` to replace the current process with the process launched by the arguments and how are commands executed after that?

Comment: That's my bad, I'm to tired to think right now.